Changing the "GIT Repo URL" from GitHub to Bitbucket is still showing the result of the old code inside our Microsoft Teams Apps
I have clone this Teams Apps from GitHub:-
https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-emergency-operations-center
And I deployed it to our tenant, and it is working well.
Now the customer asked us to clone this app >> do some changes >> so we can run a version which have our customization.
So i did those steps:-

Clone the code from GitHub inside my machine
Since our client uses Bitbucket. so I modify the code locally using Visual Studio code >> then I push the changes to BitBucket
I went to the deployment template inside azure portal , and i did those modifications:-


inside the web service >> deployment Center >> define BitBucket as External GIT:-


I went to the related resource group >> select the Template >> click on Redeploy


Define the Bitbucket Url as the "GIT Repo URl" and everything went fine, did not get any deployment errors or warnings.



But when I went back to my Teams app inside Teams desktop app or inside web browser, I still see the old code output.
For example inside BitBucket repo >> I modified the LocaleStrings.ts and I changed the label for a field as follow (from been Incident Commander to Incident Controller):-

While the original label inside GitHub is:-

But inside the Teams app it is still showing the old label.. so what could be going wrong?

so why our Teams app is still referencing the GitHub code, although we explicitly define an external GIT and modify the "GIT Repo Url" inside the template to reference BitBucket??
Thanks
